# How to write ngrx/effects unit test case if i use delay observable?

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, rxjs, angular5, ngrx-effects

My Effects

```
@Effect({dispatch: false}) getStudents = this.action.pipe(
  ofType(GET_STUDENT),
  delay(0),
  tap(() => this.api.getStudents())
 )
```

How to write unit test case for the above ngrx/effects, mainly how to use delay observable in that?

Comment: How to achieve the above UT without rxjs marble testing?